# Trying to make a clickable user list so people can send messages easy

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create an easy way to send messages on my website.
Function:
 1. You will see all users on the website.
 2. You click the user you want to write to.
 3. When chosen you get tansferred to a place where you can write the message.
 Problem is the following:
`"echo "<p><a href='send.php?user=$user'>$username</a></p>;`is not working and, DW says there is something wrong, what can I do about this or should I try to use another method?
Best regards, Peeth!

```
       <?php
          if(isset($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['user'])){
    echo "start new conversation";
        }else{
    $user_list = mysql_query("SELECT id, username FROM users");
    while($run_user = mysql_fetch_array($user_list)){
        $user = $run_user['id'];
        $username = $run_user['username'];

        echo "<p><a href='send.php?user=$user'>$username</a></p>;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this out and do advise**

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['user'])){
        echo "start new conversation";
    } else {
        $user_list = mysql_query("SELECT id, username FROM users");
            while($run_user = mysql_fetch_array($user_list)){
                $user = $run_user['id'];
                $username = $run_user['username'];
                echo "<p><a href='send.php?user=". $user . "'>" . $username . " </a></p>";
            }   
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for a quick answer! I will mark it as the correct answer as soon as possible!

Comment: The problem was a missing quotation mark. Concatenating strings is not necessary when you're using the double-quote. This code works, yes, but the reason is because Mark corrected the missing quote, not because you need to add all those concatenations ("string" - dot- $value -dot- "string") to your code.

Answer (score 0):

There's just a tiny error:

```
echo "<p><a href='send.php?user=$user'>$username</a></p>; <--- where is the double quote ? :)
```